# Button isn't working

Tags: android, button, android-studio

So guys, i'm creating an app, and in this layout I show 2 EditText, when the user click's either of them it show a popup menu, and when they click in an item of the popup menu it will set the text of edittext to the same text of the item they clicked. This part is working. But then i'll have a button, wich will do certain things, but i was just testing this button, to see if it was working, but nothing happens when i click the button, i dont know why. Here's the code:

```
public class horariosMenu extends Activity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horarios_menu);

    Button buttonProcurar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProcurar);
    final EditText deTextPartida = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deText);
    final EditText paraTextDestino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.paraText);
    buttonProcurar.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    verifica(deTextPartida.getText().toString(), paraTextDestino.getText().toString());
                }
            }
    );
}


public void showPopUp(View view){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(horariosMenu.this);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_locais, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.show();
}

public void showPopUpMenu_Para(View view){
    PopupMenu popupMenuPara = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popupMenuPara.setOnMenuItemClickListener(horariosMenu.this);
    MenuInflater menuinflaterPara = popupMenuPara.getMenuInflater();
    menuinflaterPara.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_locais_para, popupMenuPara.getMenu());
    popupMenuPara.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    EditText deText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deText);
    EditText paraText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.paraText);
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.id_Coimbra:
            deText.setText("Coimbra", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_SJoao:
            deText.setText("S. Joao", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_SSilvestre:
            deText.setText("S. Silvestre", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_SMartinho:
            deText.setText("S. Martinho", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Tentugal:
            deText.setText("Tentugal", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Carapinheira:
            deText.setText("Carapinheira", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Montemor:
            deText.setText("Montemor", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Maiorca:
            deText.setText("Maiorca", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Figueira:
            deText.setText("Figueira da Foz", null);
            return true;
        //EDIT TEXT "PARA":
        case R.id.id_Coimbra_Para:
            paraText.setText("Coimbra", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_SJoao_Para:
            paraText.setText("S. Joao", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_SSilvestre_Para:
            paraText.setText("S. Silvestre", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_SMartinho_Para:
            paraText.setText("S. Martinho", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Tentugal_Para:
            paraText.setText("Tentugal", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Carapinheira_Para:
            paraText.setText("Carapinheira", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Montemor_Para:
            paraText.setText("Montemor", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Maiorca_Para:
            paraText.setText("Maiorca", null);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_Figueira_Para:
            paraText.setText("Figueira da Foz", null);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void verifica(String a, String b) {
    if (a == b) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Partida e destino nao podem ser iguais, escolha de novo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

}

The buttons is only suppose to work, at least for now, when the text of both EditText are the same. That's why i call the verifica(String, String) function, and when i'm testing i put both the same and it doesn't work.
can you guys check what's happening ?

Comment: Just add a Toast in onClick() and see if the Toast is displayed..just for debugging..

Comment: @Lal "just for debugging"? I mean the way to debug is to attach the debugger and press the button. No need to recompile, reinstall and rerun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Toast must be shown from UI thread use `runOnUiThread`

Also you need to show the toast

```
Toast.makeText(...).show();
```

And for comparing string you should use `equals`

Comment: Bah, you are right, the button was working, i just missed the .show() .
I'm retard ahah thx man

Answer (score 0):

Probably your button is working. You can't compare two string with `==`. You have to use `compareTo` function for comparing string.

```
public void verifica(String a, String b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b)) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Partida e destino nao podem ser iguais, escolha de novo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } 
}
```

Comment: when i do that it gives me an error, says : "Incompatible types, required: boolean, found : int" 
I dont have any int values here O.o